# Apache2 SSL configuration in several files?

Tags: ssl, configuration, apache2

I have setup Apache2 with SSL on a Debian Linux (squeeze) box. In the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl the SSL Engine is already configured and working. Packages with web software often come with an extra pkg-apache.conf file with some virtualhost, alias and directory directives. How could I make such package available via https without putting the content of pkg-apache.conf into default-ssl? Adapting the  to *:433 results in load errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Include` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) within your SSL virtual host to point to your extra configuration file. You'll need to make sure that the directives within that extra file can be used within a `VirtualHost` section.